# Issue in validate a mobile number in javascript

Tags: php

I had created a form with a mobile field and added the validation code for mobile number using javascript code to accept only 10digit numbers.

Same code I had used in another form it is working fine but when I use here it is not working.

Please can any one help me.

Form.php

```
  <form action="" id="bookingtest" method="post">
    <div class="fieldset">
    <ul class="form-list">
        <li>

            <label for="mobile" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Mobile Number') ?> </label>
                        <div class="input-box">
                            <input id="mobile" name="mobile" value="" class="input-text required-entry" title="<?php echo $this->__('Mobile Number') ?>" />
                        </div>
         </li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="button">
<p class="required"><?php echo $this->__('* Required Fields') ?></p>
    <button id= "submit"  type="submit" class="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Book Test') ?>" name="send" id="send2"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Book Test') ?></span></span></button>
  </div>


  </form>


  <script type="text/javascript">

 //<![CDATA[
var dataForm = new VarienForm('bookingtest', true);
 //]]>
   </script>

<script type="text/javascript">
   //<![CDATA[

if(Validation) {
    Validation.addAllThese([
    ['validate-mobileno','Enter correct mobile number (Eg:9986858483)',
    function(v){
    //var timePat ="^((\+){0,1}91(\s){0,1}(\-){0,1}(\s){0,1}){0,1}9[0-9](\s){0,1}(\-){0,1}(\s){0,1}[1-9]{1}[0-9]{7}$";

    var timePat ="^{0,1}9[0-9](\s){0,1}(\-){0,1}(\s){0,1}[1-9]{1}[0-9]{7}$";
    // var matchArray = v.match(timePat);
    if(v.length > 0){
    if(v.length !=10){
        return false;
       }else if(v[0]!=9 && v[0]!=8 && v[0]!=7){

        return false;
       }


    return true;

    }else {
    return false;
    }

    }
    ]])};

var contactForm = new VarienForm('bookingtest', true);
  //]]>
  </script>
```

Comment: if this is custom page check that js files for validation is loaded on your page varien/form.js

Comment: i believe , this magento framework

Comment: But the code it self php and it is related to javascript.can you please suggest me to solve my problem or change my code to display as my need.Thanks in advance

Comment: are you getting any js error ? check on console

Comment: No error.But when I click submit button it is taking special characters and more than 10 digit number.

Comment: i have added answer try that

Comment: Can you please tell me the changes what you have done.

Comment: You have created 2 object for same form 
var dataForm = new VarienForm('bookingtest', true);  and 
var contactForm = new VarienForm('bookingtest', true); and placed validation before form VarienForm object

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91552/discussion-between-minesh-patel-and-mouni).

Comment: No.It is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<form action="http://www.labwise.in/devel/zensearch/order" id="bookingtest" method="post">
    <div class="fieldset">
    <ul class="form-list">
        <li>
            <label for="mobile" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Mobile Number') ?> </label>
             <div class="input-box">
            <input id="mobile" name="mobile" value="" class="input-text required-entry validate-mobileno" title="<?php echo $this->__('Mobile Number') ?>" />
            </div>
         </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="button">
    <p class="required"><?php echo $this->__('* Required Fields') ?></p>
    <button id= "submit"  type="submit" class="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Book Test') ?>" name="send" id="send2"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Book Test') ?></span></span></button>
  </div>
  </form>


<script type="text/javascript">

if(Validation) {
    Validation.addAllThese([
    ['validate-mobileno','Enter correct mobile number (Eg:9986858483)',
    function(v){
    //var timePat ="^((\+){0,1}91(\s){0,1}(\-){0,1}(\s){0,1}){0,1}9[0-9](\s){0,1}(\-){0,1}(\s){0,1}[1-9]{1}[0-9]{7}$";

    var timePat ="^{0,1}9[0-9](\s){0,1}(\-){0,1}(\s){0,1}[1-9]{1}[0-9]{7}$";
    // var matchArray = v.match(timePat);
    if(v.length > 0){
    if(v.length !=10){
        return false;
       }else if(v[0]!=9 && v[0]!=8 && v[0]!=7){

        return false;
       }


    return true;

    }else {
    return false;
    }

    }
    ]])
};
var dataForm = new VarienForm('bookingtest', true); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you have missed out calling Validation function on submit button click. It should be something like this...

```
<button id= "submit"  type="submit" class="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Book Test') ?>" name="send" id="send2" onclick = Validation(); ><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Book Test') ?></span></span></button>
```

Can u share the issue u were facing?

Comment: I am not any alert message or any thing it is taking when i enter some thing like this :99*441jkk.It should not validate like this.It has to take only numbers

Answer (score 1):

You can use following function for mobile number so that user will only be able to type numbers in the text box for mobile number.

```
<script>
// allow only number to be typed in textbox
    $("#mobile_no").keypress(function (e) {
        //if the letter is not digit then don't type anything
        if (e.which != 8 && e.which != 0 && (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57)) {
            return false;
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: It has a limit to only to enter 10 digits,If enter other than 10 digits or special characters it has to show the message as "your number is not validated"